# How to set encoding for sqitch in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, sqitch

I installed sqitch for snowflake deployment in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
Now after running

```
sqitch verify --target dev
```

I get the following:

```
ø°ø°®ø ·ø¬ø« (SQL-)
```

Looks like bad encoding.

Any thoughts how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it could be performed as follows:

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Add two lines above to:
`sudo vi .bash_profile`